# timers.timer not firing exactly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using timers.timer to fire an event at every 5 seconds. What i noticed is after some time it is firing at every 6 seconds. There are lot of other threads running parallely. The timers.timer event will be generated using threadpool.The drift is because of other threads running paralley. Is that correct? my app is wpf app. I can't use dispatcher timer since it might affect UI.

I want to fire a timer event at every 5 seconds irrespetive of othere threads and without affecting UI. What are the solutios/best approaches.

Comment: Out of 21 questions you've asked on StackOverflow you only accepted 6 answers, were the other answers so bad?

Comment: Oh dear you really need to accept some answers to lure people in giving more answers... Every one wants some credit for their effort. That's why this site exist..Its not Ask.com

Comment: sorry guys...i didn't mark answers. i will do it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about why is this happening but timer.timer is not ment for that purpose.  if you are going to have many concurrently running timers on different threads then consider using System.Threading.Timer .

System.Threading.Timer is a simple, lightweight timer that uses callback methods and is served by thread pool threads. It is not recommended for use with Windows Forms, because its callbacks do not occur on the user interface thread. System.Windows.Forms.Timer is a better choice for use with Windows Forms. For server-based timer functionality, you might consider using System.Timers.Timer, which raises events and has additional features.
have a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: The System.Threading.Timer is a better solution for server type projects but it suffers from the same problem.  It's still on threads from the threadpool and so can't be relied upon to fire with any accuracy.

Comment: Well for that comparison i would like you to have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx